# Cursor not moving automatically to next TextField 

Tags: iphone, ipad, cursor, uitextfield, move

I am new to gaming apps. I am trying to implement question and answer game in which we have text fields. When you type a letter it automatically moves to the next text field, but it is not moving automatically for the second textfield. Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

```
 int i=0,k=0;
        while(i<len)
        {
            int y = 15 +k*44;
            int j=0;
            for(j=0; j<15;j++)
            {
                if (i>=len) 
                    break;

                if([[CharArray objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:@" "])
                {
                    NSLog(@" space i value:%d",i) ;

                    NSNumber* spaceValues = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
                    [intArray addObject:spaceValues];
                    NSLog(@"intArray values :%@",intArray);
                }
                else
                {
                    letterField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
                    // letterField.text = [CharArray objectAtIndex:i];
                    [letterField setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
                    [letterField setFrame:CGRectMake(30*(j+1)+1*j, y, 30,30)];
                    letterField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:27.0f];
 [letterField setTag:tagCount+300];
                    letterField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
   letterField.delegate = self;
                    [answerView addSubview:letterField];
  [letterField release];
                    tagCount ++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            k = k+1;
        }
        [viewToGuess removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:answerView];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:answerView];
        answerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 904, 768, 100);
```

I am using this code for getting the TextField and I use keypress notification for this:

```
nextTag = nextTag + 1;  //increment the tag value while key press.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are using the same logic for the second time it will not work, am i right? I think you forgot to allocate textfields

and

```
 UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:nextTag];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

if you use this you may got what you want

Answer (score 0):

Whichever text field has to be highlighted, it has to be made the first responser.
For example:

```
if(letterField.tag == _YOUR_TAG_VALUE_)
    [letterField becomeFirstResponder];
```